# Meaning of でも or ちょうだい in テレビでも見てちょうだい

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

Two kids are playing 'house' ままごと. The speaker is happy. The person she is speaking to has just suggested that it's pointless.

> 「まったくおとうさんは現実的なんだから。さあ、テレビ**でも**見てちょうだい。ほら、キンちゃんがでてるわよ」
>   Good grief, it's because you're pragmatic. Come now, *please watch TV*. Look キンちゃん is on.

I'm either failing to understand でも or ちょうだい in this sentence. I thought verb-てちょうだい meant 'please do verb'. In which case I can't make sense of でも with a meaning of 'even' or で+も as two separate particles.

My initial thought is that I am misunderstanding ちょうだい. If I take it to mean 'won't you do' rather than 'please do'. Then I can have "Won't you even watch TV?"

Comment: Does it say 「見て」 and not 「見てて」?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> 「まったくおとうさんは現実的{げんじつてき}なんだから。さあ、テレビ**でも**見{み}て**ちょうだい**。ほら、キンちゃんがでてるわよ。」

Easier item first -- 「Verb in て-form +ちょうだい」.  The only thing this can express is a friendly request.  No exceptions.  "please do ~~"

Next, the not so easy -- 「でも」.  Here, it does not mean "even".  It is used to give an example (as in suggesting an action) instead of making a clear statement as in an imperative or declarative.  It simply means "**~~ or something**" rather than "this or that".  Please know that this usage of 「でも」 is ***very*** common.

「コーヒー**でも**、どうですか？」 ("How about grabbing a coffee or something?")

「ひまなら助詞{じょし}の勉強{べんきょう}**でも**したら？」 (If you have spare time, why dontcha study Japanese particles or something?)

> 「テレビでも見てちょうだい。」 means:
>
> "Why dontcha watch TV or something!" or "Please watch TV or something!"

Comment: Great answer; I believe this is the same usage of でも　in テニスでもしませんか？