# Question about "でも" in this particular sentence

Tags: particle-でも

So my question is about this "**でも**"

> 眠れないもので顔**でも**洗ったら少しはいいかと思って…

I think i know what the sentence means :

> "Because i was unable to sleep, i thought washing my face/splashing
>   water on my face a bit would have been a good idea.."

But even do i get the overall meaning of this sentence, i was unable to explain what this "でも" meant here precisely..

Is it "-or something like that" ?

Is it use because otherwise the sentence would mean that the guy/girl took a COMPLETE shower?

How can i be sure of the PRECISE meaning?

Thanks!

edit : **Yes, this でも means "or something like that", indicating face washing is not the only option.** <- this feel like a good additional information to keep.

Comment: Highly related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42204/meaning-of-%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82-or-%e3%81%a1%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%a0%e3%81%84-in-%e3%83%86%e3%83%ac%e3%83%93%e3%81%a7%e3%82%82%e8%a6%8b%e3%81%a6%e3%81%a1%e3%82%87%e3%81%86%e3%81%a0%e3%81%84/42207#42207

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this でも means "or something like that", indicating face washing is not the only option. Although this でも is placed between 顔 and 洗う, it means "(I should) do something like face-washing" rather than "(I should) wash something such as my face". The sentence means he/she could do something totally different to kill time and get relaxed, like watching TV, cleaning his room, or whatever.

Comment: Ohh, thanks  ! It is much clearer for me now.