# What is the function of でも in this sentence (as an ending particle)?

Tags: grammar, particle-でも

「また、次の機会にでも。」
The translation given is “May I take a rain check.” Is this でも being used as the ‘or something’ or is it more of like ‘(with) next time (too) ?

I’m wondering then if it might have the same feel as “Would another time be okay, or…?” in English. I know Japanese is prone to a lot of trail-off sort of finished sentences but I’m curious about how exactly this works out.

I’d appreciate it if somebody could dissect this for me. Apologies if I did not word my question best, this is my first post here.

Comment: related/duplicate https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13463/the-use-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-and-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-in-this-sentence https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/42204/meaning-of-%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-or-%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%E3%81%84-in-%E3%83%86%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E8%A6%8B%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A1%E3%82%87%E3%81%86%E3%81%A0%E3%81%84/42207#42207 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48068/what-particle-is-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-and-what-does-it-mean

Answer (score 2):

This でも is a particle that means "maybe" or "or something (else)".

また次の機会に simply means "(See you / Try) next time". また次の機会にでも indicates the speaker is less certain about if there will be an explicit "next time". What it actually implies depends on the context. Maybe the speaker simply has no future plan, but it could imply "You don't have to wait, contact me anytime," or it could imply "I doubt you'll get another chance."