# What would be the difference between 殺さなければ and 殺すのでもなければ?

Tags: grammar, conditionals

> 「手前ェのしたことを心底思い知って、後悔して這いつくばって赦してくれって泣き喚いてんのをぶっ**殺すんでもなきゃ**、到底復讐にはならねえ。……けど、これだけ今まで恥知らずな真似ばっかりしてきやがった白ブタどもが、今更反乱だの皆殺しだの程度で反省なんかするわけもねえだろ。手前ェの無能と無策は棚に上げて、他の誰かの無能と無策を罵りながら悲劇の主人公気取って、被害者面してくたばるだけだ。……そんなクズどもの自己陶酔のために、誰が同じものに成り下がってやるものかよ」

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

Can we use 殺さなきゃ for the bold part? What would be the difference between 殺さなければ and 殺すのでもなければ?

Answer (score 3):

Here, ぶっ殺す is used with **でも** meaning "something like ～" or "～ or something". There is also a nominalizer ん (の) to turn ぶっ殺す into a noun.

- [Meaning of でも or ちょうだい in テレビでも見てちょうだい](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42204/5010)
- [Meaning of "でも" in "食事でもどうですか？"](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21519/5010)

Compare:

- 彼女でなければ解けない問題
  a problem only she can solve
  <sub>(She is the only person who can solve it)</sub>
- 彼女でもなければ解けない問題
  a problem only a person like her can solve
  <sub>(Technically, anyone as capable as her could solve it, but the bar is very high anyway)</sub>

So:

- ～をぶっ殺さなきゃ、到底復讐にはならねえ。
  It's never gonna be a vengeance unless I kill ～.
- ～をぶっ殺すん**でも**なきゃ、到底復讐にはならねえ。
  It's never gonna be a vengeance unless *it's something like* killing ～.