# 海にでも散歩してほしいね Does に work here?

Tags: particles, particle-に, particle-で

> A: 何故台風はいつも休日に来る？
> B: 台風も休みだから散歩なんじゃない？
> A: (1) 台風も生きてるのか... なら海にでも散歩してほしいね

A native speaking friend made a joke but their use of に doesn't sound quite right to me. Shouldn't it be 場所で散歩?

> (2) 公園にでも散歩しに行こう

sounds fine because に comes with 行く

> (3) 公園にでも散歩すればいいのに

I can't pinpoint why but this sounds slightly better to me than 1. Does に work in 1 and 3? IF so is it because 行く is implied? Does で work?

Related: [でも and other particles: conjunction, exclusion, and word order](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/94470/30454)

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but wouldn't 散歩 work with を instead of で?

Comment: What's the context? Is there any reason it was not 海を? Where was the typhoon at this point?

Comment: @jarmanso7 That's a great point. I was under the impression both を and で would work but there are some nuances.

Comment: @naruto The context is banter, two people making jokes. I think typhoon was nearing Japan when the jokes were made, as the conversation literally took place yesterday.

Comment: As a much more common example, Xに遊ぶ・Xで遊ぶ both works although Xに遊ぶ is usually used in the sense *to study without specific purpose in X*. So by a very rough analogy, 散歩する could take に, but it sounds rather irregular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, に doesn’t usually work with 散歩する. The first and third sentences sound equally awkward to me, if not incorrect. If some think they are acceptable, it would be because they feel the sense of either （散歩しに）行く or （散歩しながらそこに）いる. If you find the third sentence less bad than the first, that could be because you feel a stronger sense of 行く in it. In this case, it would be more like “go away” than just “go.”

The particle should be either を or で. The latter sounds like you perform the action of strolling within the boundaries of the place marked with it, or in other words, under the circumstance of you being in that place. を, on the other hand, puts greater focus on the traversing movement through the specified place.

海 in 海を散歩する or 海で散歩する is normally understood as referring to the beach or shore. It doesn’t mean you walk through or on the water. However, we are talking about a typhoon here, and this changes the meaning of 海 a little. Your friend was probably referring to the state of the typhoon loitering over the ocean. Then, で seems to work at least as well as を.

Having said that, though, I would think most people would say 海でも. Even some of the people who would choose で over を might not say 海ででも. It sounds clumsy.

---

[Edit]

If you want to keep で, you could say 海で散歩でもしてほしい.

---

[Edit2]

The sentence in my first edit would sound odd in the dialog added in the question later. See the comments below.

Comment: How would you say "take a stroll *to* the beach"? 海まででも?

Comment: @Kaskade - I would say 海まで散歩する. If I have to add でも in the sense of "... or something", I would say 海まで散歩でもする.

Comment: I added more context. I think they might have had 海にでも行け in mind?

Comment: @EddieKal - I guess so. They said に probably because the main focus of the sentence was not the act of strolling (because that was already said by the other person) but where to go. 海を／で散歩でもしてほしいね (with でも attached to 散歩) would have been an odd response in this context. 海にでも行ってほしいね would have been completely natural. They ended up with an uncommon verb-particle combination because they repeated the verb from the previous line when they didn’t have to. 海（で）でも散歩してほしいね would have been still fine.